# Conjunction necessary if there is comma?

Tags: conjunctions

Do we need the conjunction 'and' along with comma, or we can leave it just with comma in below sentence?

> With the help of these properties, a human being is able to behave *as if* the external or internal situation were different from that which reasonable experience (observation) says (the boundary is not always clear)**, and** were more – or less – in line with one’s wants and needs.

Comment: That sentence needs to be reworked, extensively. It has several issues (e.g., word choice: *says*??), but most obviously, it goes on and on between the two *were*s. The second *were* really isn't enough to smoothly pick up where the first *were* left off…so long ago.

Comment: I'm not impressed with the text either, but don't think the (optional) comma is relevant. The word ***and*** can't possibly be discarded, but I see no problem in throwing out the second instance of 'subjunctive' ***were***. Personally, I think it's actually ***easier*** to parse without the second ***were***, because I can almost persuade myself there's a deleted ***are*** rather than ***were*** (the sooner I can forget that subjunctive, the better! :)

Answer (score 0):

The "and" is required as it joins co-ordinate clauses. The comma is a matter of opinion/style/choice.

> With the help of these properties, a human being is able to behave
>
> **{**(i) as if the external or internal situation were different from that which reasonable experience  says[,]
>
> **and**
>
> (ii) *[as if  the external or internal situation]* were more – or less
> – in line with one’s wants and needs.**}**

The comma is used between the first two items of a list of **three or more** items and implies the conjunction in the context.

"The balls come in three colours: red, blue[,] **and** green." -> the comma after "red" is understood as "and". The comma after "blue" is considered a pause comma, not a conjunctive comma.

"You can choose one colour: red, blue[,] **or** green." -> the comma after "red" is understood as "or". The comma after "blue" is considered a pause comma, not a conjunctive comma.